# How to texture large objects?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have recently completed a model of a maze, however, I am having a hard time texturing it. It's one big object, and I have no idea how to texture it to get a good resolution, can anyone tell me how to texture it with a good resolution.

[image: maze object]

Comment: you have two main options: 1) reuse parts of your texture. 2) have a BIG texture map.

Comment: Are you willing to bake it o use in a game or will you use it internally?

Comment: Use it in a game engine(Unity).

Answer (score 3):

I see there are a lot of boxes and hard angles in your mesh. As a result, you could try something like this, if you are okay with a certain level of randomness.

[image]

Basically, it uses Blender-generated *Texture Coordinates* and the *Box* preset found in the *Image Texture* node. The scale values on the *Mapping* node determine how much the texture is spread out. You can adjust different ones until the texture displays to your liking. There is also a *Bump* node to make the plants look less flat. If you so desire, you could also look into the *Displace* modifier for additional bumpiness. All of this info is fed through a standard *Diffuse BSDF* shader.

I found a simple leaf texture on [textures.com](http://www.textures.com/download/groundplants0077/13132?q=Groundplants). It is seamless, so you should not be able to tell where one iteration start/ends. You can simply download a low-res version here:

[image]

Lastly, this is an example of how the texture might look on your maze.

[image]

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

=Puck

Answer (score 2):

1) Use images that are of equal width and height. (Avoid odd numbers)
2) Reduce the size of images as much as possible without losing the detail you want. 
3) Make as many textured faces as possible as equal-sided as possible.
4) Reuse textures as much as possible.